# How to force Aptana Studio 3 to automatically refresh project explorer?

Tags: refresh, workspace, aptana3

This setting is enabled by default in Aptana Studio 3, but I had forgotten what it was.  I'm currently using git, which is irrelevant, but the following is the best example of what I can explain is happening.  Basically, whenever I change a file, the project explorer doesn't refresh to indicate that there are changes ready to be staged until I left click on the appropriate files.

I initially turned off the option to try to speed up the program, but now I'd like it back on.  Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these settings:

- General > Workspace > Refresh using native hooks or polling
- General > Workspace > Refresh on access

Comment: I have both these settings but it still does not work.